# Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the unit Disk D with $f(0) = f'(0)=0$, show that $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{z}{n})$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in the unit Disk D with $f(0) = f'(0)=0$, show that $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac{z}{n})$ is holomorphic. I should probably start out by showing that g(z) is well-defined, that is the left hand side converges. The idea is to produce some kind of bound for $f(\frac{z}{n})$, but I am not sure how to do that. Also, how to show the right hand side is analytic(my guess is to use the Wierstrass theorem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac {f(z)} {z^{2}}$ is bounded and holomorphic on  compact subsets of $D$. This makes the series uniformly convergent on compact subsets of $D$ and hence the sum is holomorphic. [ Power series expansion makes the first statement clear. For the uniform convergence on compact sets use M-test].

Comment: May I also ask when will g(z) = kf(z) for some constant $k$?

Comment: I think $g(x)=kf(z)$ iff $f(z)=z^{m}$ for some $m$.

Comment: May I ask about your reasoning. I think the correct answer should be that $f(z)= cz^2$ for some constant. You do not have to answer this, I can think about it for some time or start a new question. Thank you very much.